# TypeScript error when using Remix action inferred types

Tags: typescript, remix, zod

;tldr
Has anyone successfully used `zod` for server side validation in Remix while using the new(ish) type inference for the action function?  `const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>()`.  I can get it to work when I am only handling a single form action, but when handling multiple actions with different `zod` signatures I am having issues parsing the errors back in the component.

### Background

Up until now I have been blindly using `useActionData()` and `useLoaderData()` without any explicit type casting, but recently ran into a need to pass the action data down to a child component and wanted to get better autocomplete.  This led me down a rabbit hole of issues.

I started on `Remix v1.6.4` (prior to implementation of `typeof loader`).  After looking through the more recent releases, decided I would update to latest `v1.7.2` to get the inferred types and now have a slew of errors.

For simplicity's sake, I am handling multiple for actions on a single route and using `Zod` to server side validate.  Any errors are formatted and returned, then consumed by the original elements to display the errors and keep the form inputs in sync.  I believe my TS issue has to do with the error object that is returned by `zod`.

### Code

```js
export async function action({request}: ActionArgs) {
  const form = await request.formData()
  let { _action, ...values } = Object.fromEntries(form.entries())

  const FormInputs = z.object({
    some_string: z.string().min(1),
    some_enum: z.enum(['enum 1', 'enum 2']),
    some_date: z.date(),
    some_bool: z.boolean(),
  })

  const validate = FormInputs.safeParse(values)
  if (!validate.success) {
    const errors = validate.error.format()
    return json({fields: values, errors}, {status: 400})
  }

  try {
    // do some async stuff
  } catch(error) {
    // do something with error
  }
 return redirect('/some/redirect')
}


export default function RouteComponent() {
  const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>()

  function hasErrors(input: string) {
    return {
      flag: actionData?.errors?.[input as keyof typeof actionData.errors] ? true : false,
      message: actionData?.errors?.[input as keyof typeof actionData.errors]._errors[0] // <-- This throws error
    }
  }

  return <form method="post">...Some form components</form>
}
```

This methodology was working fine before updating to `v1.7.2` and adding type inference.  The error thrown is: `Property '_errors' does not exist on ...[long type mostly of zod errors]`

The exact type when I hover `actionData` is:

```
const actionData: SerializeObject<Simplify<{
    fields: {
        [k: string]: FormDataEntryValue;
    };
    errors: z.ZodFormattedError<{
        some_string: string;
        some_enum: "enum 1" | "enum 2" | "enum 3";
        some_date: Date;
        some_bool: boolean;
    }, string>;
} & {}>> | undefined
```

### What I've Tried

- Manually typing action and passing as generic `const actionData = useActionData<MyActionType>()`
- Type casting to manual type `const actionData = useActionData() as MyActionType`
- Type casting to unknown first `const actionData = useActionData() as unknown as MyActionType`
- My original code used `actionData?.errors?.[input]?._errors[0]` in the `hasErrors()` function, but it threw a `cannot index errors with type string`.

Removing zod and returning a static object of the same format does get rid of the errors, but obviously that is less than ideal.  I'm sure someone has run into this since `Remix v1.6.5` released.  Would love to figure out how to properly use the inferred types and pass back the `zod` errors directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just focusing on the error message:

```
Property '_errors' does not exist on ...[long type mostly of zod errors]
```

The issue seems to be that you are calling `hasErrors` with something that is not in the object returned by the `format` method. From testing out that method on my own, it seems like only fields that have errors are returned in the result. Indexing without `?.` will give you the error you are seeing because you're then trying to index `[0]` on the `undefined` value that was returned.

> My original code used `actionData?.errors?.[input]?._errors[0]` in the hasErrors() function, but it threw a `cannot index errors with type string`.

It seems like you already addressed this problem for yourself by casting `input` to `keyof typeof actionData.errors`. Doing the same in the code you wrote with `?._errors[0]` should work if I'm not mistaken.

In general, I would suggest avoiding typecasting if you can, however. Is it possible to update `hasErrors` input type from `string` to `keyof typeof actionData.errors`?

To summarize, does this work?

```
function hasErrors(input: keyof typeof actionData.errors) {
  return {
    flag: Boolean(actionData?.errors?.[input]),
    message: actionData?.errors?.[input]?._errors[0],
  }
}
```

Comment: That does work when there is only one error return as shown in the sample code, but when I have multiple actions returning different error keys it complains again. I believe it is because the inferred type is assuming the object contents are literals. My workaround so far has been to get it back to a general object with string keys and string values so that I can just check for any inputs existence.  It boils down to not having a good way to narrow the type union that is returned by the inferred action type.